# ExtJS collapse panel doesn't work

Tags: panel, extjs3

I have two panels. When I collapse the first one, the second does not fit the empty space. While if I collapse the second it works well.

```
this.firstpanel= new Ext.Panel( {
        region: config.propertyRegion, 
        id: config.editorpropertytable, 
        border: true, 
        borderBody: false, 
        autoHeight: false, 
        autoScroll:true,
        split: true,
        collapsible: true,
            height: 300, width: 600, minSize: minSize, maxSize: maxSize,
});

this.secondpanel= new Ext.Panel({
            region: config.previewRegion, 
            id: Ext.id(), 
            autoScroll:false, 
            border: true, 
            borderBody: false,
            collapsible: true,
            split: true
        });
```

I noticed that the arrow button for collapsing panels are different, but I don't why.
[image: Panels not collapsed]

First panel collapsed
[image: First panel collapsed]

Second panel collapsed
[image: Second panel collapsed]

Comment: Please tell us what `config.previewRegion` and `config.propertyRegion` are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a [BorderLayout](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/3.4.0/#!/api/Ext.layout.BorderLayout), the collapsable space is **always** filled by the mandatory `'center'` region.